# How to call a URL

Tags: vb.net, web-services

In VB.NET how can I call a URL using the POST method?

I am trying to utilize the API of a website but because I have no experience in web services, I don't know how to do this simple code.

If this question confuses you, or I need to add more information please ask!

Comment: This can easily be found with a Google search.  Try "vb.net post to url"

Comment: You might not be asking the right question, maybe you should ask how to use Web Services. It's completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `HttpWebRequest` class, or the newer and better `HttpClient` class.